# If $a_n \sim b_n$ and $a_n \leq c_n$, when does $b_n \leq c_n$ also?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be positive sequences with $a_n \sim b_n$. Suppose also that for some other positive sequence $(c_n)$, I have $a_n \leq c_n$ for all $n$. Also suppose that $a_n$ and $b_n$ alternate only finitely many times.

I would like to say that:
$$b_n \leq c_n \textrm{ eventually }$$
i.e. there exists $N$ such that $b_n \leq c_n$ for all $n \geq N$. Clearly the statement isn't true in general, for example taking $a_n = n$, $b_n = n+1$, and $c_n = n$. So what is the weakest assumption I can impose to guarantee this holds in general?

The specific case I'm looking at is where all the sequences $a_n, b_n, c_n$ are $\in (0,1)$ and increasing to $1$. But I'm curious about the general case too.

Comment: It may be hard to find a useful formulation, even in your specific case. Take $c_n=a_n$, and let $b_n$ alternately be ahead of and behind $a_n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas good point. maybe for simplicity I will suppose that $a_n$ and $b_n$ alternate only finitely many times.

Comment: $b_{n} = o(a_{n})$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @GudsonChou but $a_n/b_n \to 1$, so...

Comment: @GudsonChou, I would love to see an example of sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $b_n\sim a_n$ and at the same time $b_n = o(a_n)$.

Comment: I intended to say $b_{n} = o(a_{n})$ alone with $a_{n} \leq c_{n}$ suffice; concerning not your $a_{n} \sim b_{n}$. Given your reaction, good luck in finding your dream conditions.

Comment: @GudsonChou I was just pointing out that your comment contradicts the question. I'm sorry you took offense to that.

Comment: Two simple extra conditions are $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{c_n}{a_n} > 1$$ or $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n - a_n}{c_n - a_n} < \infty,$$ but maybe they aren't very useful. You probably won't be able to get a condition which just uses asymptotic notation since it isn't fine-grained enough for this kind of thing.